# How to upgrade SharePoint-hosted app without losing data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

I create a SharePoint-hosted app but when this app is redeploy then Data should be Lost.

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding to lose exist data in SharePoint Add-ins (SharePoint-hosted) there is two way to do that :

- If you did a modification just in your **scripts or css** you can use
     [SPFastDeploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCurranMVP.SPFastDeploy)
- I prefere you to use this way is to **map Network drive with your App web**
  Follow this [link](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/01/error-windows-cannot-access-mapping-master-page-gallery-as-network-drive/) replace **master page path** with **your App Web path**.

> Note : If you modify **list** or **content type** or **site column**
>   or **Workflow** so you need to redeploy.